# searching within all keys in a multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I want to search all keys within a multidimensional array for a specific string. I just need to work out if its present, nothing more. I want to know if an IP of a visitor is present within any of the arrays.

Is there a php function or method I can use to do this, each one I've tried always returns false. (in_array, array_search, array_filter)

I was hoping to avoid looping through each key and set of values.

*Example Array*

```
Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 21
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:56:57
            [url_id] => 11
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 22
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:57:05
            [url_id] => 12
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 23
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 18:42:42
            [url_id] => 10
        )
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can never avoid the loop :-)

```
function search($array, $searchString){
   foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(in_array($searchString, $val)) return true;
   }
   return false;
}

//use it like so:
if(search($array, '109.148.183.1')){/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a way you wouldn't have to loop (at least yourself):

```
$term = preg_quote('109.148.183.1', '~'); // lets make sure it's safe
$result = array_map('unserialize', preg_filter('~' . $term . '~', '$0', array_map('serialize', $data)));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

With your example data:

```
$data = array
(
    21 => array
    (
        'click_id' => 21,
        'ip_addr' => '109.148.183.1',
        'dtime' => '2011-04-28 17:56:57',
        'url_id' => 11,
    ),

    22 => array
    (
        'click_id' => 22,
        'ip_addr' => '109.148.183.1',
        'dtime' => '2011-04-28 17:57:05',
        'url_id' => 12,
    ),

    23 => array
    (
        'click_id' => 23,
        'ip_addr' => '109.148.183.1',
        'dtime' => '2011-04-28 18:42:42',
        'url_id' => 10,
    ),
);
```

It correctly returns keys (`21`, `22` and `23`) that have the value `109.148.183.1`:

```
Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 21
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:56:57
            [url_id] => 11
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 22
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:57:05
            [url_id] => 12
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 23
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 18:42:42
            [url_id] => 10
        )
)
```

---

And since this is a regular expression we are able to do even more powerful searches, for instance searching for all `2011-04-28` dates that have an *odd number of seconds*:

```
$term = '2011-04-28 [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9][13579]';
$result = array_map('unserialize', preg_filter('~' . $term . '~', '$0', array_map('serialize', $data)));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 21
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:56:57
            [url_id] => 11
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [click_id] => 22
            [ip_addr] => 109.148.183.1
            [dtime] => 2011-04-28 17:57:05
            [url_id] => 12
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$matching_keys = array();

function search ($item, $key) {
  global $matching_keys();
  // do your testing here, stuff matches in $matching_keys, or however you wanna do it
}
array_walk_recursive($array, 'search');
```

Alternatively you could write your own recursive function and avoid the use of a global. This is just the most direct way.